# How do I make and plot ROC curves in R for multiclass classification?

Tags: r

I am doing my degree work, I am studying the GAUSSIAN MIXTURE MODELS (GMM), which I am using to carry out classification, as I am using the GMM for classification, it is of interest to me to see how accurate the model is being as a classifier. I am working with a dataset that has 5 labels, which refer to 5 classes of Rice, I split the dataset into test data and training data and ran the GMM using the `Mclust` function from the `mlcust` library in `r`, I would like to know how I can make a ROC curve for this case of multi-classes, and calculate the AUC, I saw that with a graph of the type 1 vs all it was possible, but they do not detail how, the examples that are found in other places do not run well, and for so it's easy to see how it works

I enclose an example code of the GMM using iris, for this case I would like to see what the ROC curves would be like

````
library(mclust)

Datos<-iris

set.seed(2022)

indices<-sample(1:nrow(Datos),size = floor(0.40*nrow(Datos)),replace = FALSE)
entreno<-Datos[indices,]
prueba<-Datos[-indices,]
table(Datos[indices,]$Species)
X<-Datos[indices,-5]
y <-Datos[indices,5]



GMM_iris<-Mclust(X,G=3)
summary(GMM_iris,parameters = TRUE)
table(y,GMM_iris$classification)

prediccion<-predict(GMM_iris,newdata = prueba[,-5])
table(Datos[-indices,]$Species,prediccion$classification)```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can plot roc curves of multiclass classification model with `pROC`.

```r
library(mclust)
#> Package 'mclust' version 5.4.9
#> Type 'citation("mclust")' for citing this R package in publications.

Datos<-iris

set.seed(2022)

indices<-sample(1:nrow(Datos),size = floor(0.40*nrow(Datos)),replace = FALSE)
entreno<-Datos[indices,]
prueba<-Datos[-indices,]

X<-Datos[indices,-5]
y <-Datos[indices,5]


GMM_iris<-Mclust(X,G=3)



table(y,GMM_iris$classification)
#>             
#> y             1  2  3
#>   setosa      0 21  0
#>   versicolor  0  0 22
#>   virginica  17  0  0

prediction<-predict(GMM_iris,newdata = prueba[,-5])


library(pROC)
result <- pROC::multiclass.roc(prediction$classification, 
                               as.numeric(prueba$Species))
```

`prueba$Species` was changed to `numeric` for `multiclass.roc`.

```
plot.roc(result$rocs[[1]], 
         print.auc=T,
         legacy.axes = T)
plot.roc(result$rocs[[2]],
         add=T, col = 'red',
         print.auc = T,
         legacy.axes = T,
         print.auc.adj = c(0,3))
plot.roc(result$rocs[[3]],add=T, col = 'blue',
         print.auc=T,
         legacy.axes = T,
         print.auc.adj = c(0,5))

legend('bottomright',
       legend = c('setosa-versicolor',
                  'setosa-virginica',
                  'versicolor-virginica'),
       col=c('black','red','blue'),lwd=2)
```

There are 3 rocs in `result`, which is the number of combination of iris species. 
(setosa & versicolor, setosa & virginica, versicolor & virginica).

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I get  plot with an x-axis range from -1 to +2, clearly not a sensible range for an ROC curve.

Comment: @IRTFM You can adjust x-axis range from 0 to 1 with `xlim=c(1,0)`.

Comment: Of course you can. I was merely pointing out that either you were getting a different result than I was seeing for reasons that were not apparent in your code. Whether the different is due to sloppy coding in the package or differences in the way our respective setups operate is unclear. I think those results might better be displayed with extraction of probabilities in a tabular display.